# ScrollController in StatelessWidget

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it **ok** to use a `ScrollController` for a `ListView` within a `StatelessWidget`. If so, how can the controller be disposed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a `ScrollController`, I think that you probably has a State (to change or maintain) in your widget.

In that case you need to go for a `StatefulWidget`.

I would just change to a `StatefulWidget` and use the `dispose()` method to clean memory.

But first of all, think if you controller has a purpose to exist in the first place. Maybe in your case makes sense.

Check this answer too --> [Do stateless widgets dispose on their own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55549663/do-stateless-widgets-dispose-on-their-own)