# Do all widgets in Flutter have the "bool this.mounted" property?

Tags: flutter, lifecycle, application-lifecycle, statefulwidget, statelesswidget

Peace be upon you

I am researching Flutter's widget lifecycle and stopped at a point which is the `this.mounted` boolean variable, it does exist directly in the `State` class, which can only be connected with a `StatefulWidget` as a subclass and never will/did with a `StatelessWidget`.

> The question is ...
>
> Do all widgets actually contain the `bool this.mounted` variable as some say here in [[this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53379776/9768854), [this article](https://fluttercentral.com/Articles/Post/1206/Flutter_Stateful_And_Stateless_widgets) and [this](https://www.developerlibs.com/2019/12/flutter-lifecycle-widgets.html#:%7E:text=All%20widgets%20have%20a%20bool%20mounted%20property) ], or not?

I searched in Flutter and found this [mounted](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/mounted.html) variable only in the `State` class, then I looked further to find a function called `mount()` inside the `Element` class.

The `StatelessWidget` class is connected to the `StatelessElement` class, which extends from the `ComponentElement` that inherits directly from the `Element` class.

I'm really confused right now, maybe I misunderstood this, I need an explanation for this please!, Thank you.

Comment: There is an option to get `mounted` getter using wrapped stateful widget https://stackoverflow.com/a/74843298/4559034

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why that answers says `all widgets`. But `NO`.

Only `State<T>` objects are the ones that have a `getter` named `mounted`.

This is easy to verify, Just `cmd + click` or `ctrl + click` on any `State` you have in your class which will redirect you to a file called `framework.dart` which is located at `flutter -> package -> flutter -> lib -> src -> widgets` path.

Search `mounted` and this line is the only actual declaration that you will find.

```
bool get mounted => _element != null;
```

And that's part of the `State` class' code.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you my friend but I was thinking maybe .. just maybe, StatelessWidget has a "mounted" boolean but it's private because we don't need a getter for it since the widget is immutable ?!, Just wondering.

Comment: Even if it were private, it would still show up in the code, right ? I have searched through the code for mentions of `mounted` and only the `State` widget had that variable. You can open the framework code at the path I have mentioned and check yourselves.

Comment: Private or public, the variable should atleast be in the code. If there were something with the same idea but with some different name, then we wouldn't know. But for sure, there is no other `mounted` in any other class.

Comment: Alright then, I'll accept your answer cuz we can't deny the fact that there's no `mounted` property other than the one in the `State` class.

Comment: Cool Thanks. I'll do some more research on the actual `_element` variable that the `mounted` is based on and update you if I get across anything.

Answer (score 14):

In the future versions of Flutter (currently `3.3.4` on the stable channel) `BuildContext` will have a getter `bool mounted` so you can use it in stateless widgets:

See this PR which adds the getter:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/111619

## Update:

This has been released with Flutter `3.7.0`. You can now use `context.mounted` in stateful and stateless widgets.

Comment: Valentin [updated](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/111619#issuecomment-1306718556) that this will be available >= `3.4.0`, possibly later.

Comment: `context.mounted` is soo pretty to StatelessWidget`s. thanks