# Which should I use, StatelessWidget or StatefulWidget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using `StatelessWidget` in my code now. I have `TextEditingController` in `build` method of `StatelessWidget` and I want to add `dispose` method to dispose it. However, the `dispose` method is only available in `StatefulWidget`. Do you suggest me to change `StatelessWidget` to `StatefulWidget`?

My code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: TextField(controller: controller),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55549663/16124033), but it doesn't answer my question, because its question is whether StatelessWidget will does it by itself.

Feel free to leave a comment if you need more information.

Which should I use, `StatelessWidget` or `StatefulWidget`? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do stateless widgets dispose on their own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55549663/do-stateless-widgets-dispose-on-their-own)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the `StatefulWidget` for your code if you add to [dispose](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html) method to your `TextField`

`StatelessWidget` not support to `dispose` method. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52918871/13997210) answer

If you used Android Studio Editor for coding just move your cursor to `StatelessWidget` and press `alt + enter` and wrap it `StatefulWidget`

If you used VS Code Editor for coding just move your cursor to `StatelessWidget` and press `ctrl + .` and wrap it `StatefulWidget`

Refer more for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55549663/13997210) question also

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! So you recommend I use `StatefulWidget`?

Comment: @MyCar Yes I recommend to  use `StatefulWidget` Widget

Comment: Ok I will listen to your opinion

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `StatefulWidget` as the `dispose` method come inside `StatefulWidget`. `StatelessWidget` does not support dispose method.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! So you recommend I use `StatefulWidget`?